# whats wrong with the following code for thread in java?

Tags: java

```
class threaddemo extends Thread

{
    Thread t ;
    t=Thread.currentThread();//error(incompatible type. thread cant,t be converted to t)
    String s=t.getName();


    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+" "+t.getName());
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(threaddemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rephrasiing the question might help (and by the way it seems that you gave the answer yourself `thread cant,t be converted to t`. So the real question might be "Why does assigning Thread.currentThread() to Thread variable raise a compilation error?" Besides the rest of the code seems more to distract from the original problem (i.e. the `for` loop, which could have left out by replacing with `...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do initialisation like:

```
Thread t ;
t=Thread.currentThread(); //error(incompatible type. thread cant,t be converted to t)
```

if you are outside of a method.

If the variable is a field of a class, you basically* have to do declaration and instantiation on one line:

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
```

---

*I say basically because this is not strictly true. You can also use constructors, for example:

```
class MyClass
{
    String str; //declaration

    MyClass()
    {
        str = "hello"; //instantiation
    }
}
```

There is at least one other method which is less common and I wouldn't worry about for now. [This page of Oracle's site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) describes it.